# Opening a new file whose parent directory doesn't exist yet

Tags: files, directories

When opening a new file whose parent directory doesn't exist yet, I  either open a shell window, or an Emacs shell buffer, and then `mkdir` the directory in it. I find this cumbersome. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to do that, if that's your question.

`C-x C-f /some/new/directory/newfile.txt`

Emacs prints a message to let you know that the directory `/some/new/directory/` does not yet exist: `Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents`.

Insert text into the new buffer for new file `newfile.txt`.

`C-x C-s` to save the file.

Emacs asks you whether you want to create the missing intermediate directories (e.g., `new/directory/`.  You hit `y` for "yes".

Not very cumbersome, IMO.  The UI needs to ask you for confirmation, because you could easily have mistyped the name of an existing directory.

Comment: You can also just use `M-x make-dir` `tab` (tested from `emacs -Q` to be sure that works) `RET` `RET` and it will create the directory without any further prompting.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin: Yes, of course. (That's what the message says.) But if you have already opened the new file buffer, just try to save it and confirm dir creation with `y`.

Answer (score 7):

#### For `ido` users

- Do <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> (which should call `ido-find-file`) and enter a non-existent path.
- Press <kbd>M-m</kbd> (mnemonic for `m`ake new dir?). Hit <kbd>RET</kbd>.
- Continue with typing the new file name that you want to create in that new dir. Hit <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

When in this situation, emacs should have told you something like:

```
use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents
```

> Is it cumbersome?

I'll say, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make `find-file` to automatically create parent directories when not already exists, you can do the following in your init file.

```el
(defun my-find-file (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let* ((filename (car args))
         (directory (file-name-directory filename)))
    (if (not (file-directory-p directory))
        (make-directory directory t))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'find-file :around 'my-find-file)
```

After all, Emacs was designed to be extensible and customizable.

Reference:

- [Advising Named Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html)
- [Advice combinators](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-combinators.html)
- [File Name Components](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html)
- [Kinds of Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Kinds-of-Files.html)
- [Create/Delete Dirs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Create_002fDelete-Dirs.html)